# Switch pandas Multi-index level column to header row

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this dataframe (result of a groupbyagg) :

[image: ![enter image description here]

Unitcount is the only column. Product and Day are multi-indexes.
I'd like to know if there is any way to move the 'day' multi-index level to headers. Here's the output I am looking for :

[image]

The order of days is not important for now, i'm just curious to know if this kind of switch is possible with Pandas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for correct order of columns:

```
cols = ['LUNES', 'MARTES', 'MIÉRCOLES', 'JUEVES', 'VIERNES', 'SÁBADO', 'DOMINGO']
df = df['day'].unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(cols, axis=1)
```

Comment: @JeanleChevalier - What is your code for `groupbyagg` ?

Comment: means=df.groupby(["product", "day","hour"]).agg({"unitcount": "mean"})
When I run your 2 lines I just get 'Keyerr: day'

Comment: @JeanleChevalier - Are you sure? In sample data is not `hour`. Is it not `means=df.groupby(["product", "day"]).agg({"unitcount": "mean"})` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, after my group by agg I did this : df3=means.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()    and then applied your line to df3

Comment: @JeanleChevalier - Yop, so then it working? Because ouput from `df3=means.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()` has no `RangeIndex`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234156/discussion-between-jean-le-chevalier-and-jezrael).